# How to validate this type of condition in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a field named password. I want to validate it in such a way that
If it is entered then it should be minimum of 6 characters and maximum 16 characters.
If user doesn't enter anything then It should not through any error.

```
$request->validate([
                       'password' => 'required|min:6|max:16'
                   ]);
```

Comment: Hmmm, if the user is allowed to enter nothing then the field CANNOT be REQUIRED surely ???

Comment: Why do you want to limit your users passwords to 6-16 characters? The only thing that does is harm security, like _most_ password restrictions.

Comment: Yes RiggsFolly, You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'password' => 'nullable|min:8|max:16',
```

Comment: You're welcome, Actually I'm using this in my projects.